# Problem with color of equation-label

Tags: tikz-pgf, stix

Why does this numbered equation have (1) in blue? I
I'd like that (1) is in black.
How must I do? Thx
The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

\newcommand{\Stirling}{\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n!}{\Tonde{\dfrac{n}{e}}^n\sqrt{2n\pi}}=1} 

\begin{document}

\section{Formula di Stirling}
\hfsetfillcolor{gray!30}
\hfsetbordercolor{red}
\begin{equation}\label{StirlingLim}
\tikzmarkin[disable rounded corners=true]{b}(0.25,-1.2)(-0.25,0.8)\color{blue}{\Stirling}\tikzmarkend{b}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

colors can leak. Add another group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

\newcommand{\Stirling}{\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n!}{\Tonde{\dfrac{n}{e}}^n\sqrt{2n\pi}}=1}

\begin{document}

\section{Formula di Stirling}
\hfsetfillcolor{gray!30}
\hfsetbordercolor{red}
\begin{equation}\label{StirlingLim}
\tikzmarkin[disable rounded corners=true]{b}(0.25,-1.2)(-0.25,0.8){\color{blue}{\Stirling}}\tikzmarkend{b}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thaank you so much